# Magento 2 - Add newsletter checkbox on checkout order summary.

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, newsletter

Can anyone help me to Add newsletter checkbox on checkout order summary? Please check screenshot for exact requirement.[image]

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: No @jack still I am looking for the solution.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223249/how-to-create-custom-checkbox-field-for-term-and-conditions-in-one-page-checkout/344623#344623

Answer (score 1):

You can try [This](https://marketplace.magento.com/mageside-module-subscribe-at-checkout.html) Extension (free) and try to change the placement of checkbox to order summary.

If you look at `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` file, you will find an item:

```
<item name="itemsAfter" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- merge your components here -->
    </item>
</item>
```

You can override this layout file and move newsletter block/container from extension to here..